# What changes in a live environment carry over to a install?

Tags: live-environment

Well, I loaded up the latest version of Ubuntu and made a MAC address change before installing it and noticed the changed MAC address carried over to a new install I made. Are there any other changes like this that can carry over?

Answer (score 2):

MAC address changes write the new MAC address to the network card. It's kept there so it will apply at moment 0 of power-up. Other changes you make to **hardware** that is staying behind will stay behind. You can mount the disks `rw`, and change anything. You cannot expect changes made to software (installs, configuration, removal, etc) while running in Live mode to persist (as the system keeps it's config on the USBstick/CD).